# How to automatically generate tick labels based on number of columns in loaded table in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I am trying to make a parallel axis plot in pgfplots but am having trouble working out how to automatically generate x-axis labels.

Here is a simplified example of what I am doing:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
0.2,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.7
0.6,0.2,0.9,0.4,0.2
0.1,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.3
0.2,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.5
0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.8
0.5,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.5
0.1,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.4
0.4,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.2
0.2,0.8,0.6,0.7,0.3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize}}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{testdata.dat}\data

\pgfplotstabletranspose[]\dataT{\data} 

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{axis}[xtick distance=1, 
             xticklabels={dummy,$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$,$x_5$}, % need to change this line
             xlabel=variable,
             xlabel near ticks,
             ylabel=scaled $x$ value,
             ylabel near ticks]
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nRows}{
\addplot[blue] table [y=\i] {\dataT};
}
% Plot code
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

My problem is that I will be generating a lot of these plots, and not all of them will have the same number of x-variables. How can I modify the line in the axis definition to use `\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\data}` and automatically generate the x-labels to be `x_1,...,x_n` according to the datafile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define how labels are printed with the `xticklabel` option.
You could use

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick+1}$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
0.2,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.7
0.6,0.2,0.9,0.4,0.2
0.1,0.9,0.6,0.8,0.3
0.2,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.5
0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.8
0.5,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.5
0.1,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.4
0.4,0.1,0.8,0.5,0.2
0.2,0.8,0.6,0.7,0.3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize}}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{testdata.dat}\data

\pgfplotstabletranspose[]\dataT{\data} 

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nRows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{axis}[xtick distance=1, 
             xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick+1}$x_{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$}, % <--- new line
             xlabel=variable,
             xlabel near ticks,
             ylabel=scaled $x$ value,
             ylabel near ticks]
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nRows}{
\addplot[blue,mark=*] table [y=\i] {\dataT};
}
% Plot code
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, thanks! and how can i make it so that it starts at x_1 for column 0?

Comment: Just realized that you want to start from 1. I updated my answer.